# Matplotlib 'key_press_event' does not respond

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

By clicking with mouse button on Figure:
`self.canvas.Fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.button_press)`

I could receive signal and generate answer by printing "Button pressed" in status bar `self.statusBar().showMessage("Key pressed", 400)`

But for some reason same piece of code does not work for key (keyboard) pressing:
`self.canvas.Fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.key_press)`

The message "Key pressed" does not appear, meaning that no event occured or no signal were received.

This is my MWE with all essential classes:

```
import sys
import matplotlib 
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QSizePolicy

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas


class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100,data=[[]],timedelay=[],wavelength=[]):
        self.Fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.Dataplot = self.Fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.compute_initial_figure(data,timedelay, wavelength)    

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.Fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,QSizePolicy.Expanding,QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def compute_initial_figure(self,data,timedelay,wavelength):
        pass

class MyStaticMplCanvas(MyMplCanvas):  
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        MyMplCanvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def compute_initial_figure(self,data,timedelay,wavelength): 
        self.Dataplot.set_xlabel('Wavelength, nm')
        self.Dataplot.set_ylabel('Time delay, ~s')

class GraphView(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.main_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)

        self.canvas = MyStaticMplCanvas(self.main_widget, width=8, height=8, dpi=100,data=[[]],timedelay=[],wavelength=[])

        self.canvas.Fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.key_press)
        self.canvas.Fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.button_press)

        self.layoutMain = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.main_widget)      
        self.layoutFigure = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.layoutMain.addLayout(self.layoutFigure)   
        self.layoutFigure.addWidget(self.canvas)


        self.main_widget.setFocus()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

    def key_press(self,event):
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Key pressed", 400)

    def button_press(self,event):
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Button pressed", 400) 

def main():
    app = QApplication( sys.argv )
    a=GraphView()
    a.show() 
    app.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

What is problem with my code?

Comment: What do you mean by *does not work*? Does the code produce an error? If so, please post the full trace.

Comment: Additionally, the provided code does not run on my machine, yielding a invalid syntax at your *app.exec()* line.

Comment: @hitzg by not working I meant that message "Key pressed" does not appear, meaning that no event occured or no signal were received.

Comment: @BasJansen, It works on my machine. I've copied code from this page and compiled it with python 3.4.3

Comment: @saldenisov Please mention that it is for python 3 in the question, because the supplied code does not run on python 2.7.

Comment: Are you pressing a keyboard key, or a mouse button? These are handled differently, i.e. see [button_press_event](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html).

Comment: @farenorth, There are 2 event handlers, one for button of mouse pressing and other for keyboard. The one which is used for keyboard does not work for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i found a solution [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/707)

after

```
self.canvas = MyStaticMplCanvas(self.main_widget, width=8, height=8, dpi=100,data=[[]],timedelay=[],wavelength=[])
```

add

```
self.canvas.setFocusPolicy( QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus )
self.canvas.setFocus()
```

click in the canvas so it has the focus, from then you will see the key_presses

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to click on the canvas every time you want to use keys, you can do the following so that the focus changes to the canvas automatically when you hover over it with your cursor. Add this to your `GraphView.__init__()`:

```
self.cid_enter = self.canvas.mpl_connect('axes_enter_event', self.on_enter_event)
```

And add the `on_enter_event` method to your `GraphView` class:

```
def on_enter_event(self, _):
    self.canvas.setFocus()
```

You also don't need to change the FocusPolicy for this to work.

By the way, you don't need to do `self.canvas.Fig.canvas` to reference the canvas object as it is circular. `self.canvas` is already the canvas object. In theory you could do `self.canvas.Fig.canvas.Fig.canvas` and so on indefinitely and still would refer to the same object.